# Accessing MFC Document from MainFrame

Tags: c++, mfc

In my MFC program, my Document class is derived from CDocument, and my MainFrame is derived from CMDIFrameWndEx.

Is there a way to access elements of my document, which is a derivative of CDocument, from the MainFrame Class?

P.S. This question is not a copy of an earlier question here, that question was only concerned with accessing elements of CDocument (not the derivative Document) from MainFrame.

Comment: MFC obeys all the normal C++ subclassing and access rules. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Check CFrameWnd::GetActiveDocument

Comment: Found a way.

First of, GetActiveDocument() returns CDocument type which cannot be used as a receiver for  member functions of CMyDocument (derived from CDocument(). 

So, instead of declaring an event handler to be a member of MainFrame, you make the event handler a member of myDocument, and then from within that handler, you call a member function of MainFrame class, and have this function return the required value.

Comment: Why don't you just cast the pointer you got from GetActiveDocument to a CMyDocument* ?